# Как управлять доступом к редактированию в DataGridView? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь понять логику допусков к редактированию. У DataGridView выставил

```
counterpartyListGV.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
counterpartyListGV.ReadOnly = false;
```

Далее через цикл пытаюсь выставить допуск к правке по столбцам (через один).

```
for (int i = 0; i < counterpartyListGV.Columns.Count; i =i+2) counterpartyListGV.Columns[i].ReadOnly = true;
```

Но они все-равно все доступны для правки! Как самому выбрать какие столбцы можно редактировать, а какие нет?

Comment: Приведённый Вами код делает `ReadOnly` только нечётные столбцы. Для чётных следует начинать обход столбцов с `1`. Так, что код полностью работоспособен. Проблема не воспроизводится. А, свойство `DataGridViewEditMode` отвечает лишь за то, что инициирует редактирование ([документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: Эм. у себя на компе я вообще все столбцы пометил как ReadOnly = true; (кроме первого), но их все-равно можно редактировать. Я не понимаю почему. Выглядит так, как будто распоряжение ReadOnly = false; для всего DataGridView нивелирует правку полей для столбцов по отдельности.

Comment: Даже с явным указанием в коде `ReadOnly = false` для `DataGridView` всё равно не воспроизводится. Возможно помимо этого в Вашем проекте есть ещё что-то, что провоцирует такое поведение. Попробуйте отследить изменение свойства `ReadOnly` в режиме отладки.